# Suitable Backend language social networking Node.js/mongoDb or PHP/Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, mongodb, backend

We are in the initial phases of developing one social networking project and off course have a tough time deciding between  Node.js/mongoDb or PHP/Mysql for our backend.

I have read a tons about the advantages/disadvantages of both of them. But i am still unsure of what to use. I am a bit inclined towards node.js combination.

here are my requirements...

The web application would be a highly dynamic with real time responses with lot of writing/reading databases (small chunk of data every time). Its like any other social network like twitter/facebook/quora where user can post comments, likes, follow and typical features of such kind of sites.

Also, as such we don't have high calculation part in backend. What we have is one time page rendering by fetching the content of database and rendering to user and then doing real time activities.

I have learned that Node.js is event driven so seems to be a better fit for that. Also we don't have as such high processing driven modules in backend.  Can you please guide me if this would be a good combination for such types of websites. Please excuse me for my english or if i posted it at wrong place.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

From my point ov view

`**highly dynamic with real time responses**`

and

`**one time page rendering**`

point you in the direction of **NodeJS** for the webserver

Regarding Mongo vs MySQL it is all abount what you need in terms of speed vs integrity, but, for lots and lots of small chunks of data I'd use Mongo.